# Joomla, standard contact-form in article

Tags: joomla, contact-form

I have site on joomla.
I have page contact (html-text and picture).

In the end of this page, how to add standard joomla contact form?

Answer (score 1):

In the components menu in the admin go to contacts.
Create a new contact and fill in the information.
You can use street address for text if you want, that is at the top or you can use miscellaneous information.
Make sure to include an email address or a link to a user so that the user's email is used.

Then make a single contact menu link to that contact from whatever menu you want it shown on.

Comment: I don't need link, I need all of this in one page.

Comment: Well then don't make the menu link.

Comment: Are you asking if you can embed a contact form in an article? Is there a reason that it has to be in an article and not in a contact form where you can, as I said, put text and so on just like in an article?  You might be able to do that by making a plugin.

Comment: I have the same need as I need to implement a contact form in a one-page style website. Any updated info on how to place a contact form in an article?

Comment: I would make a model to hold the form and then embed the module in the article. Alternatively make the page using the contact form an a layout override. Make the "page" using the "miscellaneous information" field in the contact and use a layout override to play around withe the layout. You could also use another field below the contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a component for this from the [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms). Else you can build one yourself using basic html markup.

Comment: Unfortunaly I don`t need another extension, I need to use standart joomla contact form.

Comment: This is trivial in wordpress and difficult for non programmers in joomla. A basic form is easy to make but it gets complicated quickly as you need to keep the form secure from SQL Injection for one. And you need a script to process the form. But it does look like the only way is a plugin.